# Jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I customize the ac_results class generated by the autocomplete plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$("#elem1").autocomplete("source1.php").addClass("class1"); 
$("#elem2").autocomplete("source2.php").addClass("class2");
$("#elem3").autocomplete("source3.php").addClass("class3");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/

you can specify your own class names as an option

```
    loadingClass: 'acLoading',
    resultsClass: 'acResults',
    selectClass: 'acSelect',
```

and define your CSS in a separate file (or wherever you want).